# how to convert a unique values in column into seperate columns and updating the row value from another column?

Tags: python, pandas

How to convert a unique values in column into seperate columns and updating the row value from another column?

For example I have the below df,

[image]

I want to convert the above dataframe into the below format. Is it possible?

[image]

Comment: Please add any code you might have tried already.

Comment: `df.pivot_table(index = 'ID', columns = 'Role', values = 'Email', aggfunc = ','.join).reset_index().rename_axis(columns = None)`